# Can assign [] = (), but not () = []

Tags: python

isn't it logical?

[] is a mutable data structure
while () is a immutable data structure

It has been posted as bug on http://bugs.python.org/issue23275
with a lot of discussion. I have raised the same point there but am curious why nobody raised this point before. Am I missing something here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147165/how-come-raises-no-error

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870019/why-is-it-valid-to-assign-to-an-empty-list-but-not-to-an-empty-tuple

Comment: Please don't add tags to the question title - this is done automatically.

Comment: I think this seems to be logical correct. You can assign a limited type to a more unlimited type. So it's a little like containers float can contain int and so on if we look on simple data types... mutable can hold immutable but not the way around. More general datatypes can be assigned to smaller ones. This would be my mindset.