# Why is `[] = []` a valid statement in Python?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I was surprised to learn that

```
[] = []
```

is a perfectly valid Python statement (with no effect). Also:

```
[] = tuple()
[] = set()
[] = {}
```

I gather it's trying to unpack the iterables on the right hand side, but what's an iterable doing on the left hand side of an assignment?

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870019/why-is-it-valid-to-assign-to-an-empty-list-but-not-to-an-empty-tuple

Comment: Sooooo many up-votes are on their way for not much of a reason :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: the reason is probably the OP couldn't find the duplicate answer when searching before asking (I know I couldn't). This is the nth this happened by the way, I'm thinking the canonical answer should be renamed (don't have an idea). Or, you know, just wait for the duplicates to saturate the search space of the relevant phrase :p.

Comment: @mikołak Good idea; I attempted to give it a better name.

Comment: @poke: yeah, that's slightly better, at least people looking via a textual description are more likely to find it now - thanks! Also, see [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296742/searching-for-a-phrase-including-square-brackets-how-to-make-it-work).