# Assign function's output to empty list constant in python

Tags: python, list, function, output, assign

I have found something like this in a code I'm working with:

```
[], my_variable = my_function(a, b)
```

where the output of my_function goes like:

```
return some_dict, some_list
```

This seems to work - unit tests of a system don't fail, but when I try this at the python console (assigning dictionary to "[]") it raises:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Have you seen something like this? How does assigning a dictionary (or something else) to empty list constant "[]" work?

Or it doesn't and tests are missing something...

Comment: Actual `my_function` code would be helpful - likely the first result is not a dict at all: `[], qwe = {1:1}, '12'` throws value error

Comment: `[], a = ({}, 1)` works, though.

Comment: `[a], qwe = {1:2}, '12'` works as well; `a` became 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147165/why-does-assigning-to-an-empty-list-e-g-raise-no-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870019/why-is-it-valid-to-assign-to-an-empty-list-but-not-to-an-empty-tuple

Answer (score 2):

It's because in your test file, the `return value` is `{}`.

```
>>> [] = {}
>>> [] = {1:2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack


>>> [] = []
>>> [] = [1,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Either you know more than is exposed in question, or this does not answer the question

Comment: @Kevin python dict or list as long as it is iterable.

Comment: Yep, most likely `some_dict` is just `{}` in test case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really assign to list, because it is not variable, you can use list syntax to assign to multiple variables:

```
[a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Will just assign 1 to a and so forth.

What you are doing can be expressed with this expression:

```
[] = {"a":1}
```

What python tries to do is to match amount of items in dictionary with amount of items in the list. It finds mismatch and raises an error. You could do like that:

```
[x] = {"a":1}
```