# Why does Python allow unpacking an empty iterable?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

I was writing some code and made a typo, but it didn't error. Tracing it back, I found out that these work:

```
>>> [] = []
>>> () = ()
>>>
```

This is iterable unpacking, but with no real target for assignment. Why does Python allow this? Are there situations where this is useful?

[Here's where it's defined in the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target). I would have thought you'd need at least one *identifier*, *attributeref*, *subscription*, or *slicing*, but apparently not; *target_list* is optional inside parentheses or brackets.

```
target ::=  identifier
            | "(" [target_list] ")"
            | "[" [target_list] "]"
            | attributeref
            | subscription
            | slicing
            | "*" target
```

Looking at the documentation history, this wasn't possible as recently as [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) and [2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), but assigning to `[]` was added in [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) and [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), and `()` in [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Related:

- [Why is it valid to assign to an empty list but not to an empty tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29870019/4518341) (The answer was ultimately a bug)
- [Why isn't assigning to an empty list (e.g. [] = "") an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30147165/4518341) (Answers talk more about *how* than *why*)

*Note: Since I'm asking about a design choice, answers should include references to authoritative sources like official documentation or a core dev.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [the relevant Python issue discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue23275), assigning to an empty list `[]` was actually possible for a long time, but not documented. This was considered "a fairly harmless quirk" until it was documented in 3.5. Then assigning to an empty tuple `()` was added for consistency.

In the same thread, [Martin Panter provides a possible use case](https://bugs.python.org/issue23275#msg241474):

> [...] I have used this syntax on purpose as a concise way to ensure that a generator is exhaused with no more yields:
>
> ```
> >>> def gen():
> ...     yield "partial computation"
> ...     print("computation allowed to complete")
> ... 
> >>> g = gen()
> >>> next(g)
> 'partial computation'
> >>> [] = g
> computation allowed to complete
> ```